# Changing URL of Wordpress Post Completely

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP site where I want only specific Pages to have a completely different url. For example, the Page url might be `www.domain.com/page_name` and I would like for it to be `www.someotherdomain.com/page_name`. Is this possible with WP and if so how do I go about doing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is a privately hosted WP site.

Comment: Free site hosted on wordpress.com or your own site hosted yourself using Wordpress (.org)?

Answer (score 0):

Trying similar now, if you are using a mac and need the htaccess file install the show hidden files widget to find the htaccess file. I am still learning to and am not completely sure how to do it.

Visit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Hope you find how.

Answer (score 0):

Two plugins can do this for you...

one is "page links to" it will put a new field at the bottom of the edit page where you can put whatever url you want it to go to.

the other plugin is more robust, called "Redirection" it will allow you to make redirection rules from within the wordpress admin interface.

either one will do what you need.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried and eventually got it to work, I don't know if it was exactly needed or if I was previously doing something wrong but I would recommend it. I am using MAMP on a Mac too.

http://www.vodahost.com/vodatalk/wordpress-ultimate-blog/22326-fixing-pretty-permalinks-mod_rewrite-wordpress-blogs.html